# Unable to connect to mongodb from camel

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

In my camel RouteConfig.java I am not able to connect to mongo database. I get the following exception :
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: myDb of type: com.mongodb.Mongo
        at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryLookup(CamelContextHelper.java:130)
        at org.apache.camel.component.mongodb.MongoDbComponent.createEndpoint(MongoDbComponent.java:43)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:91)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:461)
        ... 42 more

RouteConfig.java
    from("jms:queue:Test").bean(new SomeBean()).to("mongodb:mydb=flights&collection=tickets&operation=insert");

camel-context.xml

Any help is appreciated

thanks
Lokesh

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if you use mongodb with the version >= 3. You should use class `com.mongodb.MongoClient` instead of `com.mongodb.Mongo` in your bean definition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup mongodb as a bean in the registry. If you use Spring then its just a

```
<bean id="mongodb" class=...>
```

And if you use Java then you need to add that to one of the Camel registry implementations such as JndiRegistry or SimpleRegistry.

If you have the Camel in Action book then see chapter 4, section 4.3 which covers the Camel registries.

Comment: I have a very strange situation like this one. the bean is in the context (in #configure when I log this.getContext().getRegistry().lookupByName("myMongoDb") the object is there... but the route can't be created due to `No bean could be found in the registry for...`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps :

1. Setup MongoDB Configuration.

```
@Bean
MongoClient mongoClient() {
  return MongoClients.create(
    MongoClientSettings.builder()
      .applyConnectionString(
        new ConnectionString('mongodb://root:example@localhost:27017'),
      )
      .build(),
  );
}
```

2. In the router, use

```
   .to(
  'mongodb:mongoClient?database=rtp&authSource=admin&collection=rtp_outbox_t&operation=findAll',
 );
```